# Google App Script Pivot Table List of all values

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, pivot

I am creating an automation script for KPI reporting via pivot table. It's working great but the script is not flexible, because I can't choose which KPIs I want to use. It would be great if there would be a list with all values I can choose to add to the pivot. Does anybody have an idea?

```
function pivotTableTest() {
  // Ask for the source spreadsheet name
  // Has to enter with range!
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sourceSpreadsheet = ui.prompt("Enter the sheet name:");
  Logger.log(sourceSpreadsheet.getResponseText());
  Logger.log(sourceSpreadsheet.getSelectedButton());
  
  // Create Pivot Table
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange(sourceSpreadsheet.getResponseText());
  var pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('B3').createPivotTable(sourceData);

  // Add Rows
  var pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(3);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(1);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(4);
  
  // Add Values
  var pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(8, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.SUM);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(7, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.AVERAGE);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(9, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.AVERAGE);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(10, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.AVERAGE);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(11, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.AVERAGE);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(5, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.AVERAGE);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(6, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.AVERAGE);
}
```

[image: Example spreadsheet]

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample Spreadsheet **with no sensitive data** so that it is easier for us to understand what you are trying to achieve? Would this list you want to filter come from the source Spreadsheet? Could you also show your desired output vs your actual output? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Yeah sure! The list I want to filter comes from the source spreadsheet. So you have in the first column the KPIs range. For example: A1 = "KPI1", B1 = "KPI2", C1 = "KPI3" etc. I created an example Spreadsheet and took a screenshot.

Comment: When I run my script it' defined which row the script will ad. For example: pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(1, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.AVERAGE); - now the row one (A1:11) will add.

Comment: My problem is: this method is not flexible. I want to select which one the script should add. For example: I choose B ("name) , D ("name") and E ("name").

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a link to your sample Spreadsheet so that it is easier for us to figure out how to solve this? So in this case would ```month``` be your ```KPI1```, ```name``` your ```KPI2```, etc? Do you want a function where you enter or choose ```B,D and E``` and then it creates a pivot table with just those three columns?

Comment: Hey, it's not so easy to share a sample Spreadsheet, because of the company. I try to explain it better: 
I have x KPIs. For example: 5 rows. The 5 rows has different names. For example: A = "conversion_a", B = "conversion_b", C = "conversion_c" etc.
The script will create a pivot table. In the pivot table the script will add "name" and "type" as column. 
The next step is to add values. Here I want that the script ask me which values I want to add. So I could choose add "conversion_b" and _conversion_c". Or for the next time I can choose "conversion_a" and "conversion_c"

Comment: The problem right now is, that the order is every time the same. Like the script add first "conversion_a", then "conversion_c" etc. But this is not flexible. Its the same order every time. But I don't want to use the the same KPIs for every reporting. I could change the integer value in the script, but this is also a lot of work.

Comment: Hi ! Is the image you provided in the question your desired resulting pivot table or is it the data source? I think you will probably need to modify the [addRowGroup](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-table#addrowgroupsourcedatacolumn) value but before providing any answer I want to make sure I know how the source data is structured. Would it be possible for you to create a **sample** Spreadsheet where you display an example of your source data without providing any company information (just create a new sheet and populete the cells with random values) ?

Comment: Hey sorry for the last respond. I've fixed my problem by using a custom html sidebar. But I have one another problem: How can I update the existing PivotTable with PivotValues?